# Ternary heapsort in python 2.7

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, python-2.7

I am trying to implement ternary heap sort, where every parent of the heap has 3 children, however I can not get my code to return a sorted list. I think I may be making a logical error somewhere but can not spot it, any help fixing this code would be much appreciated.

```
def swap(i, j):
    sqc[i], sqc[j] = sqc[j], sqc[i]

def heapify(end,i):
    l=3 * (i + 1)
    m=3 * (i + 2)
    r=3 * (i + 3)
    max=i
    if l < end and sqc[i] < sqc[l]:
        max = l
    if r < end and sqc[max] < sqc[r]:
        max = r
    if m < end and sqc[max] < sqc[m]:
        max = m
    if max != i:
        swap(i, max)
        heapify(end, max)

def heap_sort():
    end = len(sqc)
    start = end / 2 - 1
    for i in range(start, -1, -1):
        heapify(end, i)
    for i in range(end-1, 0, -1):
        swap(i, 0)
        heapify(i, 0)

sqc = [2, 7, 1, -2, 56, 5, 3]
heap_sort()
print(sqc)
```

`[7, 1, -2, 56, 5, 2, 3]` is what is returned, completely out of order.

Comment: What *does* it return?

Comment: @msanford http://ideone.com/KxbIeQ

Comment: [7, 1, -2, 56, 5, 2, 3] is what is returned, completely out of order.

Comment: @Kay My point was that that should be included inline the original question, both for reasons of post longevity and because it makes for a more complete question. I can download and compile anything from this site myself but that's not really how it's supposed to work, is it? That aside, thanks for the link.

Comment: Sorry I am new to coding and python, I will remember this for next time.

Comment: When you run into logic errors like this, I would scrap what you have written, start from scratch and every time you implement one logical function test that it does exactly what you expect. Either that or debug it and test that every line does exactly what you expect.

Comment: I don't get how a ternary heap works, so let me ask some questions.(1) So in a binary heap, `A[i]` has children `A[2*i]` and  `A[2*i+1]`. How does it work in a ternary heap? (2) In a binary heap, the parent is less than both of its children. Same for ternary heap? (3) In a binary heap, `sift` or `heapify` is in a loop. Same for ternary heap, right? I don't see that in your code.

Comment: Thanks so much for your code hughdbrown.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept one of these answers if you find that it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code

```
def heapSort3(a):
    def sift(start, count):
        root = start
        while root * 3 + 1 < count:
            r3 = root * 3
            upper = min(count - r3, 4)
            children = list(range(r3 + 1, r3 + upper))
            min_child = min((a[i], i) for i in children)
            v, i = min_child
            if a[root] > a[i]:
                a[root], a[i] = a[i], a[root]
                root = i
            else:
                break
    count = len(a)
    for start in reversed(range(count // 3 + 2)):
        sift(start, count)
    for end in reversed(range(count)):
        a[end], a[0] = a[0], a[end]
        sift(0, end)
    return a
```

## Test on sorted and reverse-sorted

```
for i in range(2, 25):
    print '-' * 30
    data = list(range(i))
    sorted_data = heapSort3(data)
    print i, sorted_data
    data = list(reversed(range(i)))
    sorted_data = heapSort3(data)
    print i, sorted_data
```

## Test on shuffled data

```
from random import shuffle
for i in range(1, 100):
    print '-' * 30, i
    expected = list(reversed(range(i)))
    for _ in range(5000):
        data = list(range(i))
        shuffle(data)
        sorted_data = heapSort3(data)
        assert sorted_data == expected
```

## Reference

Adapted from [this code](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Heapsort#Python). Sort of.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that merely corrects your `heapify` function:

```
def swap(series, i, j):
    series[i], series[j] = series[j], series[i]

def heapify(series, end, i):
    firstchild = 3*i + 1
    lastchild = min(firstchild + 3, end)
    children = list(range(firstchild, lastchild))
    maxelem = max((series[j], j) for j in [i] + children)
    maxval, maxindex = maxelem
    if maxindex != i:
        swap(series, i, maxindex)
        heapify(series, end, maxindex)

def heap_sort(series):
    end = len(series)
    start = end / 2 - 1
    for i in range(start, -1, -1):
        heapify(series, end, i)
    for i in range(end-1, 0, -1):
        swap(series, i, 0)
        heapify(series, i, 0)
    return series
```

## heapsort changes

You can also change your `heapsort` code to this, but it is not necessary:

```
def heap_sort(series):
    end = len(series)
    start = end // 2
    for i in reversed(range(start)):
        heapify(series, end, i)
    for i in reversed(range(end)):
        swap(series, i, 0)
        heapify(series, i, 0)
    return series
```

## Test on your data

```
>>> sqc = [2, 7, 1, -2, 56, 5, 3]
>>> print heap_sort(sqc)
[-2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 56]
```

## Test on random shuffled data

```
from random import shuffle
for i in range(1, 100):
    print '-' * 30, i
    expected = list(range(i))
    for _ in range(5000):
        data = list(range(i))
        shuffle(data)
        sorted_data = heap_sort(data)
        assert sorted_data == expected
```